# AngularJs Testing Sinon spy

Tags: angularjs, sinon

I am new with Sinon so I wanted to check whether a specific function is being called, this is what I got:

```
terminalController.controller('CashAcceptorController', [
    'PaymentService',
    '$rootScope',
    '$scope',
    'PayingInfo',
    '$interval',
    '$location',
    function (PaymentService, $rootScope, $scope, PayingInfo, $interval, $location) {
     PaymentService.start();
....
]);
```

In tests, I try to check that PaymentService.start() is called on controller instantiation:

```
describe('CashAcceptorController', function() {

var PaymentService, rootScope, scope, PayingInfo, $interval, $location;
var mySpy  = sinon.spy(PaymentService.start());;
beforeEach(module('eshtaPayTerminalApp.controllers'));

beforeEach(module('eshtaPayTerminalApp.services'));


beforeEach(inject(function($controller, 
        $rootScope, _PaymentService_, _$interval_, _PayingInfo_) {

    $interval = _$interval_;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    rootScope = $rootScope.$new();
    PaymentService = _PaymentService_;
    PayingInfo = _PayingInfo_;

    rootScope.serviceNumber = 'm1';
    rootScope.phoneNumber =  '05135309';

    $controller('CashAcceptorController', {
        $rootScope : rootScope,
        $scope : scope,
        $location : $location,
        _PaymentService_ : PaymentService,
        _$interval_:$interval,
        _PayingInfo_:PayingInfo
        });

}));


it('should call start paying', function() {
            expect(mySpy.callCount).to.equal(1);
        });
```

But this assertion fails. What am I doing wrong? Help please :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a couple of issues with your code

- The PaymentService object needs to be assigned before you can spy on it
- To add a spy with sinon you need pass the method name as a string eg. `sinon.spy(PaymentService, 'start');`

I've created a working plunk of the above at http://plnkr.co/edit/AvqS3L?p=preview

Here's the updated test code:

```js
describe('CashAcceptorController', function() {

  var PaymentService;
  var $controller;

  beforeEach(module('eshtaPayTerminalApp.controllers'));
  beforeEach(module('eshtaPayTerminalApp.services'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_PaymentService_, _$controller_) {
    PaymentService = _PaymentService_;
    $controller = _$controller_;
  }));

  it('should call start paying', function() {
    var mySpy = sinon.spy(PaymentService, 'start');
    $controller('CashAcceptorController', { PaymentService: PaymentService });
    
    chai.expect(mySpy.callCount).to.equal(1);
    
    // another way of checking that it was called once
    chai.assert(PaymentService.start.calledOnce);
  });
});
```